# How likely is it that all the air in a room spontaneously moves to one half? (if it is probable at all)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, estimation

I would like to know if this is theoretically possible or not and if there is a way of calculating the probability of this happening.

Comment: Where's the momentum going to come from?

Comment: @Alan Wendt: The walls of the room - Newton's 3rd law of motion predicts that as all the air in the room packs into, say, the left half, the room (and the building and the planet) are pushed to the right. - All the air molecules must have, directly or by proxy, kicked off from the right-hand wall within a few milliseconds.

Comment: Why not describe the circumstances, please?

Failing that are you not relying on magic or, worse, guesswork?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If we would calculate probability that air will compress "itself" by half, per time interval required for 1 molecule to travel half-room distance $L/2$,- then this "synchronized movement to particular direction" of all molecules simultaneously would be even more unlikely.

Per half-room travel molecule experiences
$$n=\frac {L}{2\ell} \tag 1,$$

collisions, where $\ell$ is mean free path of molecule. Let's assume that there is $1/2$ probability that with each hit, molecule will bounce to solid angle which directs towards required room side. Then considering that there is $N/2$ molecules in half-room, probability of them spontaneously move to the target zone at once is :

$$ P_t = \left(0.5^n\right)^{\frac {N}{2}} = 0.5^{\frac {LN}{4\ell}} \tag 2$$

Now, for the sample numbers, consider some room with area $25~m^2$ which has room diameter of $L=5~m$, and mean free path of molecule in the air is $\ell 
 = 64~nm$. Substituting this into (2) for that room gives :

$$ P_t \approx 10^{~-5,879,493~N} \tag 3$$

where $N$ is number of molecules in that room. Even without substituting $N$ into the formula it's clear enough that such probability is for all practical purposes zero.

Btw, keep in mind that if we will raise allowable time duration (make it longer) in which all molecules could "self-organize",- probability $P_t$ would be even more smaller, because with greater time duration, molecules experiences more collisions, namely :

$$ n(t)=\frac {s}{\ell} = \frac {\overline v~t}{\ell} \tag 4, $$

where $s$ - molecule accumulated travel distance, $\overline v$ is average speed of molecule. So, over time single molecule experiences more collisions and hence probability for molecule to keep required bounce solid angle becomes even smaller (probability to keep "one-directional" movement), due to independent probability addition principle. So, if you are thinking about saving your costs with not buying a vacuum/pump device,- drop it :-)

Comment: Its worth noting that "Let's assume that there is 1/2
 probability that with each hit, molecule will bounce to solid angle which directs towards required room side. " is clearly false, since the thing it hit was probably another molecule, causing the other molecule to bounce in the wrong direction. Therefore, the odds are far *far* rarer than even this

Comment: @MooingDuck If a molecule hits another molecule and bounces toward the other side, then the molecule it hit would be bouncing in the *right* direction. So in *any* molecule-molecule interaction, one is going to be going more toward the right way, and one more toward the wrong way.

Comment: I don't quite get that part: "_if we will raise allowable time duration (make it longer) in which all molecules could "self-organize_",- probability Pt
 would be even more smaller". I believe that the "infinite monkey theorem" guarantees that this will happen given an infinite amount of time. So if there is any probability > 0, then the probability is automatically 100%, no matter how small.

Comment: This estimates probability that a very specific event (much more specific than concentration to half of container) happens in a process with $n = \frac{L}{2\ell}$ collisions, which means it will take at most time around $n\frac{\ell}{v_m} = \frac{L}{2v_m}$, which for mean velocity $v_m = 1000m/s$ is 2.5 ms. People can wait for longer, and the sought probability is an increasing function of time. Also, one must also require that the other half of molecules does not move out of the half-space they start in, which decreases the probability.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield it depends on velocities of the molecules. If a fast moving molecule collides with a very slow molecule, after the collision, they move in directions that differ by a right angle, so both can move towards the correct half-space.

Comment: "For all practical purposes zero". Well, not necessarily. If your practical purpose is working out possible ways in which a Universe might spontaneously erupt, then it's of practical interest that if you leave the system in a steady state for an infinite length of time, some highly improbable events are bound to occur eventually.

Comment: @JánLalinský _the sought probability is an increasing function of time._ No. Do the math $$P_t(t) \propto 0.5^{n(t)}$$. So, it's **decreasing** over time.

Comment: @Guilherme, "infinite monkey theorem"  doesn't suits here because our probability $P_t$ is not fixed, but decreases over time, see my post edit, formula (4) and response to JánLalinský.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas that is not true, probability that a special low entropy state will be observed actually increases with time, and after a very long time it is certainty. This is due to Poincare recurrence theorem.

Comment: @JánLalinský That is total nonsense. Entropy in a closed system always increases over time. All thermodynamics laws is based on that. So low entropy state is highly improbable in natural thermodynamic system evolution. Are you saying that all room air will finally compress into singularity (point) given infinite amount of time ? That would be ridiculous. Btw, our universe also started at low entropy state and then only make entropy greater over time.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas it is a mathematical theorem for Hamiltonian systems with finite volume phase space. It is well-known that for mechanical systems, 2nd law holds only in statistical sense and fluctuations are possible. Universe has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I agree with @Ján here. "Are you saying that all room air will finally compress into singularity (point) given infinite amount of time" yes, pretty much.

Comment: I was thinking about this and I believe that can be reduced to a simple mathematical argument. Even if the possibility reduce over time, it is still guaranteed to happen. Since we are working with infinities, and that any value (that is bigger than 0) times infinity is infinity, it is pretty safe to say that if it can happen, it will happen.

Comment: @Guilherme Mathematics does not represent reality. It represents our approximation of reality. Infinity is not even an approximation in physics. It's outright false because it neglects the leading term effects. In this example proton decay will have destroyed the walls of the room long before a sufficiently large fluctuation can ever occur.

Comment: @Guilherme No, you completely wrong with your argument. At infinity $P_t = 0$, hence what you get is $0 \cdot \infty$ which is indeterminate form, unless you know exactly which function approaches which end _faster_. But, we do know that time passes linearly, while $P_t$ probability goes to 0 **exponentially**.  Hence, 0 will be reached very fast, and no time amount will help you. That's my opinion.

Answer (score 14):

The probability of one molecule being in half the room is 1/2.  The probability of them all being in half the room is $(1/2)^N$ where N is the total number of molecules in the room.

Comment: This might be better as a separate question, but are there any real-world dissipative effects (like viscosity) that would make the already tiny probability even smaller?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to attribute a "probability" to this event. It makes more sense, to me, for this to have a "probability of happening within a certain amount of time." In other words, we should have an estimate of how often this "dice" gets re-rolled. Do you have any sense of how to estimate that?

Comment: +1 I suggest adding the value of $N$ - it would be more convincing for laymen.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

Comment: @RogerVadim I'm pretty sure it's bigger than 100, which is really all you need to know :)

Comment: @AndrewChristensen I think both questions make sense. One is "If you observe the room at one instant, what is the probability that all the molecules will be in the western half of the room at that instant?" and one is "If you observe the room over some interval of time, what is the probability that all the molecules will be in the western half of the room at at least one instant in that interval?" Both of these are nonzero, but the former is much easier to estimate.

Comment: To estimate the latter, you'd basically need to have an estimate of how _long_ the molecules all stay in the western half of the room every time that that happens.

Comment: @hobbs Avogadro

Comment: +1, but this assumes the molecules are all independent of each other, which isn't realistic because collisions are significant at the scale involved. My guess is that because of this the true probability will be much lower than what you'll estimate with this method.

Comment: @user253751 yes - the only question is how much more unlikely. As mentioned in Agnius Vasiliauskas' answer the mean free path for molecules in air is in the 10s of nanometres, so it's not at all clear that collisons can be neglected in this case.

Comment: @N.Virgo for a gas that can be described within the molecular chaos hypothesis this is a really good approximation. To see if this is a good approximation you just have to calculate the "excluded volume" and for air this is minuscule wrt the volume of the room.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that if half the room is indeed somehow vacuum and half is full of air, when you add a new molecule it's just as likely to go to the vacuum side as the air-filled side? There's a distinct lack of anything related to the physical properties of air here, it's a model of coin flips. There seems to be an underlying assumption here that any fixed volume is equiprobable regardless of *whatever else is occupying the volume*.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie This assumes it is an ideal gas.  The probability relates directly to the ratio of the volumes.

Comment: @Quillo I think that's right. Having thought a bit about how I'd calculate it from the thermodynamic properties of a gas, I can see that I'd get more or less the same answer as I would from this calculation. But still, I'd say the reasons for that are somewhat non-obvious, since the molecules aren't really behaving independently of each other at all.

Comment: Jumping from $1/2$ for one molecule to $1/2^N$ for $N$ molecules would be correct if all molecules' positions were independent, which obviously they're not. The claim in this answer requires a much stronger justification (although perhaps it's impossible to justify, since it doesn't look correct to me).

Comment: @Stef In the kinetic theory of gasses, the positions are independent. Experimentally, the kinetic theory works very well for real dilute gasses, like air at ordinary densities. Of course, the situation in question is far outside the domain of feasible experiments.

Answer (score 6):

For an ideal gas, which is a good model for air at [standard temperature and pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature_and_pressure), the the chance of finding all $N$ of the particles in the same half of the volume is $(1/2)^N$, which is tiny even for $N=1000$ let alone a typical lab scale sample where $N \sim O(10^{23})$.  This probability statement can be interpreted in terms of the canonical ensemble -- i.e. it is the fraction of microstates consistent with the specified $NVT$ constraints and have all the particles in the same half of the room.

---

To turn this into an estimate of how long you'd have to wait, you need an estimate of how long it takes for the system to move to an independent state in the canonical ensemble.  This will be governed by the timescale $\tau = L/c$ where $c$ is the speed of sound and $L$ is the characteristic size of the volume under consideration.  After waiting something like thr time scale $L/c$, the system will have evolved to an effectively independent configuration of density.  So overall, you'd need to wait  a time $t$ something on the scale of $t \sim (L/c) 2^N$

This time scale can be precisely motivated by considering a box of side $L$.  The lowest mode for density (sound) waves in this box has a frequency of $c/(2L)$.  So once you wait something longer than this time, all of the modes will de-cohere relative to one another and you have an independent density configuration.  One could start with the configuration of all of the gas on one side of the room and evolve the modes to see how quickly it spreads to an effectively uniform density as a concrete example of how this works.

Comment: Could you put this in actual numbers for an example volume/temperature/air pressure?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Probability 0. Time forever. $2^{10^{27}}$ (two to the power of the number of molecules in a room of a few meters length) is uncountably huge. $L/c$ (about $10^{-2}s$) is irrelevant next to how huge it is. The difference between the number of seconds you'd have to wait and the number of lifetimes of the universe you'd have to wait is a **rounding error** on its power-of-10 representation.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 molecule in the room, then that molecule can be either in one half of the room or in the other half. The occupancy looks like 1/0 or 0/1. In two out of two  cases, all the gas in the room is in one half of the room, so the probability that all the gas in the room is in one half of the room at any given time is 2/2=1, or 100%.

If there are 2 molecules in the room, then the occupancy of the room at any given time can be 2/0, 1/1, or 0/2, so in 2 out of 3 cases all the gas is in one half of the room, and the probability is 2/3, or 67%.

With 3 molecules, the probability is 2/4, with 4 molecules it is 2/5, with 5 molecules it is 2/6, and so on. So, as long as the molecules don't influence each other (at VERY low gas density or zero pressure), the probability for N molecules is 2/(N+1).

Keep in mind that once the density of the gas increases to a level where the molecules start bouncing into each other, they will push each other in opposing directions, so the distribution of the gas in the room becomes less and less random, and besides the probability being low due to an already large number of molecules in the room, the probability further decreases exponentially with increasing gas pressure. To find a formula for this is beyond my ability at this time but the likeliness to find all molecules in the same half of the room definitely will decrease exponentially with increasing gas pressure to become infinitesimally small. This will already be the case at VERY low gas pressure close to absolute vacuum. At atmospheric pressure, the probability to find all molecules in the same half of the room will de facto be zero for that reason.

Comment: If the two molecules are N and O there are 4 cases (NO/-, N/O, O/N, -NO). These are just tags btw, not Nitrogen and Oxygen). Likewise 3 cases for 8, 4 for 16, etc. The probability will get smaller even more quickly than you have suggested.

Comment: You are right, thanks Peter. 1 molecule: probability is 2/2. Two molecules probability is 2/4. 3 molecules probability is 2/8. N molecules probability is 2/(2^N).

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible for all the air to spontaneously move and occupy just one half of the room. If you started with the state of having all the molecules in just one half and perfect vacuum in the other half, all the air would spontaneously expand and fill the whole room. The odds of having this process go in reverse, without any external input, are nil, as that would break the 2nd law of thermofynamics. What you might as well bet on is having dilute combustion fumes spontaneously concentrating themselves around the ashes and then combining to reform oxygen and the original fuel material that has been burnt down.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).